# panels expanded in viewport

Tags: extjs

in my west region panel there is smth. like the task panel here:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tasks/tasks.html

the data is loaded from 2 different 's containing only  with links
the first "task" group is always expanded to all the height of the document, though there are much less data there.

here is the code:

```
new Ext.Panel({
            region: 'west',
            title: 'דוחות',
            id: 'w',
            header: false,
            width: 190,
            split: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            collapseMode: 'mini',
            //minWidth: 100,
            baseCls:'x-plain',
            margins: '0 1 0 0',
            items: [ new Ext.Panel({
                    id:'wp',
                    frame:true,
                    title: 'דוחות לעובדים',
                    collapsible:true,
                    contentEl: 'workerRep',
                    //titleCollapse: true
                    }), 
                    new Ext.Panel({
                    frame:true,
                    id:'mp'
                    title: 'דוחות למכונות',
                    collapsible:true,
                    contentEl:'machRep',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    //titleCollapse: true
                    })
                     ]
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer, the problem was here:

```
baseCls:'x-plain',
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.layout.FitLayout` ( which is what `layout: 'fit'` stands for) is for situations when you anly have one item in a container, because it tries to 'fit' this one component to the full size of the container.

**From manual:**

> This is a base class for layouts that contain a single item that automatically expands to fill the layout's container.

If you have more than one item in container use different layout like `Ext.layout.ContainerLayout` (default one), `Ext.layout.VBoxLayout` or perhaps `Ext.layout.TableLayout`.

Comment: tried with the default layout like in the example, but it didn't work